# Prestashop : Display list Manufacturers in Footer

Tags: html, templates, smarty, prestashop, footer

I'm working with prestashop and I was thinking of How is it possible to display a list of all the manufacturer in the footer.

So in my footer.tpl I did this :

```
{if $nbManufacturers > 0}
    <div class="row">
        <h2>All manufacturers</h2>
        <ul id="manufacturers_list">
            {foreach from=$manufacturers item=manufacturer name=manufacturers}
                <li><img src="{$img_manu_dir}{$manufacturer.image|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}-medium_default.jpg" alt="{$manufacturer.name|truncate:60:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" /></li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    </div>
{/if}
```

But this isn't displaying anything... Am I bad? Is it possible or I have to use a plugin?

Comment: if you didn't change anything in php code, by default there are no $nbManufacturers or $manufacturers object available in the template. To achieve that you need or create module (if block should appears inside hook) or change core file, but first way is more acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit or create a ovverride of classes/controller/FrontController.php

inserting before

```
$this->smartyOutputContent(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'footer.tpl');
```

this

```
$this->smarty->assign(array(
            'manufacturers' => $manufacturers,
            'nbManufacturers' => count($manufacturers)
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Finally the client don't want to administrate it and he wanted only a few manufacturer in his footer... so we decided to put them directly in the HTML ... But thanks a lot!